# Горизонтальная прокрутка TextView

Tags: android

У меня такая проблема:

Есть `TextView`, текст в котором содержит символы новой строки "\n". Некоторые из строк в этом `TextView` не помещаются на экране. Мне необходимо, чтобы текст в этом `TextView` можно было прокручивать горизонтально, для того чтобы просматривать строки, которые целиком на экране не помещаются. Я сделал следующее:

```
<HorizontalScrollView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtUpload"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size3"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:text="@string/SyncActivity_commentUpload" />

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Но прокрутка не работает. Если убрать из текста символы новой строки, то прокрутка начинает работать.

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы прокрутка работала и в том случае, когда в тексте есть символы новой строки?

Я попробовал сделать прокрутку текста с символами новой строки в другом Activity. Все работает. Судя по всему причина в том, что TextView, который мне нужно сделать прокручиваемым находится внутри TableRow. Вот полный текст xml-файла:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow01"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnUpload"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/upload"
        android:text="@string/SyncActivity_titleUpload"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size" />

    <HorizontalScrollView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtUpload"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_size3"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:text="@string/SyncActivity_commentUpload" />

    </HorizontalScrollView>

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow02"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDownload"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/download"
        android:text="@string/SyncActivity_titleLoad"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBarDownLoad"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="235"
        android:progress="0"
        android:visibility="gone" >
    </ProgressBar>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView03"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size3"
        android:text="@string/SyncActivity_commentLoad" />

    </TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRowGetDB"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnGetDB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/database_save"
        android:text="@string/SyncActivity_titleGetDB"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView04"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size3"
        android:text="@string/SyncActivity_commentGetDB" />

</TableRow>
```

Каждый TableRow содержит кнопку и текст пояснения к этой кнопке. Помещать кнопку и текст в TableRow нужно, чтобы кнопки были выровнены по ширине.

Перефразирую вопрос. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы прокрутка TextView, расположенного внутри TableRow работала и в том случае, когда в тексте есть символы новой строки?

Comment: Сейчас проверил - все прокручивается и с символами перевода строки и без .. Отличий от вашей разметки - только хардкорный текст.

Comment: Важен API Level. Возможно, в каждой, это отрабатывает по разному.